# 'this' equivalent for SystemVerilog interfaces

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there an equivalent construct to `this` for *SystemVerilog* interfaces?

What I'd like to do is a bind of an interface inside some DUT block and then pass it using the UVM config DB as a virtual interface:

```
bind some_block some_interface(...);

interface some_interface(...);
  initial
    `uvm_config_db #(virtual some_interface)::set(null, "some.path", "vif", this);
endinterface
```

The workaround I have in place is to define a wrapper module that instantiates the interface and then does the config DB set:

```
module some_interface_wrapper(...);
  some_interface some_if(...);

  initial
    `uvm_config_db #(virtual some_interface)::set(null, "some.path", "vif", some_if);
endmodule
```

What I don't like with this approach is that I have to define the whitebox signals twice, once in the interface and once in the wrapper module.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Before anyone comments that this approach isn't reusable, in my code I have the path for the `set(...)` defined as a parameter that the module takes, which is assigned when it gets bound. This means any testbench can bind this module and pass it to the appropriate UVM component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [proposal](http://www.eda.org/svdb/view.php?id=4300) to use an upward reference in place of this, but nothing has been finalized yet.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to wait until 2020 to be able to do this. I'll stick with my approach for now then.

Comment: Some vendors have already implemented something that does this. Talk to them directly.